# Herramientas de asociación de preguntas entre SO y SOes

Tags: discusión, artículo, asociación-de-preguntas

<sub>Traducción semi automática de [Инструменты ассоциации вопросов между сайтами](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4857/193685) en Meta SOru, escrita por el CM [Nicolas](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/10/nicolas-chabanovsky). ¡Edita para mejorarla!</sub>

## Estadísticas

¡Los números primero!

```js
fetch("https://es.rudevs.ru/api/leaderboard/").then(resp => resp.json()).then(({items}) => { document.body.innerHTML = `<h1>Asociaciones: ${items.reduce((s,x)=>s+x.count,0)}</h1>` + items.sort((x,y)=>y.count-x.count).map(x => `<p><a href=//es.stackoverflow.com/users/${x.id}><img width=208 height=58 src="//es.stackoverflow.com/users/flair/${x.id}.png"></a> <span>${x.count}</span></p>`).join(" "); })
```

```css
body { text-align:center; counter-reset: i; } span, p::before { display:inline-block; vertical-align:top; } span { background:blue; color:white; line-height:1.5em; width:1.5em; border-radius:50%; } p::before { counter-increment: i; content: "#" counter(i) "\A0"; } h1 { color: blue; }
```

<sub>Un agradecimiento especial a @Qwertiy por implementar el código de bloque de estadísticas!</sub>

## Herramientas de asociación de preguntas entre sitios

> ### Resumen
>
> Una versión de prueba de las herramientas de asociación de preguntas está disponible en: http://es.rudevs.ru/.
>   ¡Esperamos tus comentarios y sugerencias!

<sub>*Sí, no es la mejor opción de dominio, eso es seguro. En un futuro próximo, elegiremos una nueva basada en sus sugerencias (las esperamos en los comentarios a la pregunta).*</sub>

### ¿Qué son las herramientas de asociación?

Las preguntas de asociación son esencialmente duplicados de preguntas entre sitios en diferentes idiomas: Stack Overflow en inglés y Stack Overflow en español ([para obtener más información sobre asociaciones](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4409/)). Las herramientas de asociación propuestas son una mejora en la experiencia del usuario para encontrar problemas similares entre sitios. Las herramientas contienen dos partes: una extensión para el navegador y una aplicación de servidor.

[image]

### ¿Cuál es la ventaja de las asociaciones para la comunidad?

**Atención extra**

El principal beneficio creado por nosotros en la base de conocimiento es el de nuestros colegas que acceden al sitio desde la búsqueda. Para los motores de búsqueda, Stack Overflow en español y Stack Overflow en inglés son sitios completamente diferentes, lo que puede llevar a la competencia por los primeros puestos en los resultados de búsqueda, y como resultado, a una atención insuficiente en uno de los sitios.

La creación de asociaciones entre sitios permite omitir la restricción de los motores de búsqueda y proporcionar información más útil a los usuarios sin que importe el "punto de entrada" a la colección de sitios de Stack Overflow (en otras palabras: redirigir parte de desarrolladores de habla española de un sitio en idioma inglés al sitio español; y en la dirección opuesta, si es necesario) . De esta manera, las preguntas asociadas pueden obtener más atención merecida.

**Mejora de la estructura de la base de conocimiento general.**

Hoy en día, las bases de conocimiento de las comunidades, como las comunidades mismas, no tienen ninguna relación. Una de las ideas fundamentales de Stack Overflow es reunir la mayor cantidad de información útil posible sobre cada problema de aplicación en una pregunta, lo que permitirá a la comunidad mantener la calidad de la información en las respuestas, mejorándola continuamente por un lado. Por otro lado, el resultado será la ausencia en los resultados de búsqueda de la misma pregunta formulada muchas veces. Para ello, un mecanismo para cerrar cuestiones.

La presencia de enlaces entre preguntas en diferentes idiomas brindará la oportunidad de crear una funcionalidad adicional para respaldar de manera aún más efectiva la relevancia del conocimiento presentado en las respuestas.

**Una mirada a la base de conocimientos de nuestra comunidad en términos de Stack Overflow en inglés**

Al buscar asociaciones para preguntas populares en inglés en Stack Overflow en español, puede ver qué preguntas faltan en nuestra base de conocimientos y qué respuestas pueden mejorarse significativamente.

### ¿Cómo funcionan las herramientas de asociación?

Hasta la fecha, el proceso y la implementación son los siguientes.

#### Implementación

En el lado del motor, la implementación es mínima: en Stack Overflow en inglés en la configuración del sitio, podemos establecer una cadena que contenga pares de identificadores de pregunta de los sitios del formulario soen_id=soes_id;soen_id=soes_id;.... Debajo de cada pregunta en Stack Overflow en inglés, con un identificador de esta lista, aparece un texto especial que dice que hay una pregunta similar Stack Overflow en español.

[image]

Este mensaje, en nuestro caso, se muestra solo a los usuarios de habla española de Stack Overflow en inglés.

Para que los identificadores de pares de preguntas se incluyan en la configuración de Stack Overflow en inglés, se deben crear asociaciones. La asociación se crea agregando un comentario especial en la pregunta asociada sobre Stack Overflow en español. El comentario debe tener un formato específico: la palabra "asociación", luego los dos puntos ":" y un enlace a la pregunta de Stack Overflow en inglés. Por ejemplo:

```
 asociación: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5585779/how-do-i-convert-a-string-to-an-int-in-java
```

Se permite utilizar un enlace corto (desde el bloque "compartir").

#### Proceso

Los participantes pueden agregar asociaciones en cualquier momento en comentarios a preguntas sobre Stack Overflow en español. Una vez a la semana, con alta probabilidad, los viernes, ejecuto una consulta SQL en la base de datos de Stack Overflow en español y selecciono todas las asociaciones de comentarios, formo una línea con identificadores y luego actualizo manualmente la configuración de Stack Overflow en inglés.

#### ¿Dónde están las herramientas de asociación?

Las herramientas le permiten simplificar la búsqueda de asociaciones entre sitios, automatizar la creación de comentarios y la formación de la barra de configuración.

**Detalles: [extensiones de navegador](https://github.com/chabanovsky/so_association_tools/tree/master/extension)**

1. Agrega al enlace "asociado" para cada pregunta no asociada sobre Stack Overflow en español, haciendo clic en el campo de entrada para el enlace a la pregunta - asociación en Stack Overflow en inglés.

   [image]
2. Convierte un comentario - asociación en Stack Overflow en español en un bloque especial.

   [image]

**Detalles: [aplicación de servidor](http://es.rudevs.ru/)**

La aplicación del servidor simplifica la búsqueda de problemas similares entre sitios y automatiza la adición de asociaciones de comentarios. Para trabajar con la aplicación, debe iniciar sesión a través de Stack Exchange OAuth.

La aplicación contiene cuatro secciones principales.

[image]

1. "Más vistas": una lista de preguntas de Stack Overflow en inglés, que los usuarios de habla española ven con más frecuencia. La lista se forma para cada participante de forma independiente, sobre la base de las estadísticas y las preguntas omitidas por un participante específico.
2. "Omitidas": una lista de preguntas para las cuales los miembros de la comunidad no pudieron encontrar una asociación en Stack Overflow en español. La lista es una para todos los participantes.
3. "Solicitadas": una lista de preguntas para las que probablemente no hay asociación con Stack Overflow en español y que, según la comunidad, son extremadamente importantes para nuestra base de conocimientos. Se supone que los participantes no indiferentes recrearán el conocimiento en español al traducir o publicar su experiencia sobre este tema, y ​​luego asociarán las preguntas. La lista es una para todos los participantes.
4. "Sugeridas": una lista de preguntas que los participantes agregaron manualmente a la aplicación. Se crea una selección de las preguntas más vistas en función de las estadísticas diarias de Stack Overflow en inglés. Los participantes, por otro lado, pueden agregar manualmente cualquier pregunta con Stack Overflow en inglés a su discreción para buscar una asociación. La lista es una para todos los participantes.

Seleccionar una pregunta en la lista para buscar una asociación lo llevará a la página de preguntas.

[image]

Además de la descripción de la pregunta, las estadísticas y los enlaces a ella en Stack Overflow en inglés, hay en la página:

1. El botón "saltar". Úselo si no puede encontrar una asociación a este problema. Al omitir una pregunta, ya no la verá en la lista de preguntas más vistas.
2. Botón "solicitar una transferencia". Úselo si cree que la pregunta debería estar en la base de conocimientos de la comunidad, pero aún no se ha formulado.
3. Campo de consulta de búsqueda: para buscar asociaciones en Stack Overflow en español. Utilice la consulta de búsqueda que mejor describa una pregunta en inglés. La búsqueda se realiza en un sitio en español a través de Google. Recomendamos utilizar el idioma español para el texto de la solicitud. Por defecto, el título de la pregunta está en inglés.

Después de buscar verá una lista de candidatos para la asociación.

[image]

Al seleccionar el candidato apropiado para la asociación, verá ambas preguntas con las respuestas. Si las preguntas coinciden, debe usar el botón "Asociar", si no coincide: "Regresar".

Si decide asociar una pregunta, la aplicación agregará automáticamente un comentario debajo de la pregunta seleccionada sobre Stack Overflow en español para su autoría. El comentario contendrá la palabra clave "asociación" y un enlace a Stack Overflow en inglés. No necesita hacer nada más con el propósito de la asociación. Una vez que se haya asignado la asociación, la pregunta asociada desaparecerá de la clasificación apropiada de la aplicación para todos los participantes.

### Propuestas, defectos y el futuro de las asociaciones.

La herramienta de asociación es un proyecto de código abierto: https://github.com/chabanovsky/so_association_tools . Cualquiera puede participar en la corrección de defectos y la implementación de nuevas funciones. Si ve un defecto, pero por una razón u otra no puede corregirlo usted mismo, publique una descripción del defecto en la respuesta a esta pregunta o en GitHub. Además de los defectos, en las respuestas a esta pregunta, nos complacerá ver sus comentarios y sugerencias para mejorar la aplicación.

**Futuro**

Las herramientas de asociación están en la etapa de iniciativa. Si esta iniciativa le resulta útil, asegúrese de participar en la creación de asociaciones, encontrar las preguntas adecuadas para la comunidad y publicarlas. La decisión de crear esta funcionalidad dentro del motor de Stack Overflow depende únicamente de su interés en ella. ¡Tu opinión es extremadamente importante para nosotros!

Comment: Traducción cortesía de Google Translate, revisando que no se colara ningún _desbodamiento de pila_ por allí y añadiendo imágenes propias de la versión española (falta una por añadir). Necesita revisión.

Comment: Estoy mirando la herramienta de asociación: http://es.rudevs.ru/ y tengo una duda...no hay manera de filtrar por etiqueta?

Comment: @Pikoh no me consta. Sería útil, ciertamente.

Comment: he creado un issue en github: https://github.com/chabanovsky/so_association_tools/issues/14

Answer (score 1):

Sobre las estadísticas:

1. Si uno agrega una asociación usando el método de agregar un comentario, esto no se refleja inmediatamente en las estadísticas. En lo personal entiendo la lógica de esto, mi pregunta es si se reflejarán en algún momento o plazo

   - no está implementado y debería publicarse un issue en el proyecto en GitHub
   - periódicamente, una vez al día, una vez a la semana, etc.
   - bajo solicitud

Comment: respondido en [¿Cómo funciona la asociación de preguntas entre SO y SOes](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3967/83). La clave es que Nicolas tiene acceso a un SEDE en tiempo real, no necesita esperar al dump semanal. Lo que puede pasar es que él actualice la app y haya un impasse hasta que se actualicen las settings por parte de los desarrolladores de SO.

Comment: Nicolas actualizó la app hace un rato y ya se ven las estadísticas. Como no han actualizado aún la cadena de configuración en SO, las asociaciones aún no están generadas en las preguntas de SO.

Comment: @fedorqui Muchas gracias por la actualización. Ya me alcanzó lois6b... debo apurar el paso :P