# ¿Cómo funciona la asociación de preguntas entre SO y SOes?

Tags: soporte, propuesta-de-faq, asociación-de-preguntas

Desde la publicación de [Las preguntas de SO ya pueden asociarse con las de SOes](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3960/83) y [Herramientas de asociación de preguntas entre SO y SOes](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3963/83) han surgido bastantes dudas. Recopilémoslas y démosles respuesta.

Para un buen funcionamiento de esta pregunta, listemos aquí la pregunta y vayamos respondiendo ordenadamente en la misma respuesta.

En cualquier caso, la fuente de respuestas es Nicolas, que es quien ha desarrollado el sistema. Por tanto, siempre es bueno dar una referencia en forma de un enlace a una conversación con él.

- ¿Cómo funciona el proceso exactamente?
- ¿Cada cuánto se realizan las asociaciones?
- ¿Se puede filtrar por etiquetas en la aplicación http://es.rudevs.ru/?
- ¿Las estadísticas que aparecen en [Herramientas de asociación de preguntas entre SO y SOes](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3963/83) se actualizan automáticamente?
- ¿Es obligatorio asociar las preguntas canónicas traducidas de SO?
- ¿Se puede asociar una pregunta en SO a distintas preguntas en SOes?
- ¿Se puede asociar una pregunta de SOes a distintas preguntas de SO?
- ¿Tras la asociación y mapeo, el comentario sigue siendo necesario o se borra/puede borrarse?
- El usuario que puso el comentario solicitando una asociación, ¿recibe una notificación al respecto cuando se haga efectiva?
- ¿Funciona solo en el sitio principal o también en Meta?

Comment: Otra pregunta, ¿Que pasa si se asocia una pregunta que no tiene nada que ver con otra? ¿existe un moderador que verifique entre SOes y SOen? probé la herramienta y al parecer está abierta a esta posibilidad.

Comment: @iuninefrendor técnicamente puede pasar, presumiremos buena fe. En cualquier caso, sí sería bueno poder ver todas las asociaciones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> - ¿Cómo funciona el proceso exactamente?

1. Alguien propone una asociación poniendo un comentario "asociación: `<enlace>`".
2. [Nicolas](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/10/nicolas-chabanovsky) coge los datos mediante el SEDE para empleados, que siempre contiene los datos completos (no como el SEDE público que se actualiza semanalmente).
3. Nicolas sincroniza los datos en la app.
4. Se actualiza la cadena de configuración en Stack Overflow en inglés.

([referencia](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/49332582#49332582))

> - ¿Cada cuánto se realizan las asociaciones?

Va a demanda: cuando le hagamos un ping a Nicolas en [The Terminal](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84778/the-terminal). ([referencia](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/49332535#49332535))

> - ¿Se puede filtrar por etiquetas en la aplicación http://es.rudevs.ru/?

No. [Pikoh creó un issue en el repositorio solicitándolo](https://github.com/chabanovsky/so_association_tools/issues/14).

> - ¿Las estadísticas que aparecen en [Herramientas de asociación de preguntas entre SO y SOes](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3963/83) se actualizan automáticamente?

No. Se actualizan cuando Nicolas sincroniza los datos con la app. ([referencia](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/49332266#49332266))

> - ¿Es obligatorio asociar las preguntas canónicas traducidas de SO?

No, toda asociación es opcional. Eso sí, este tipo de preguntas sería muy bueno que se fueran asociando.

> - ¿Se puede asociar una pregunta en SO a distintas preguntas en SOes?

No, actualmente no. ([referencia](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/49236672#49236672))

> - ¿Se puede asociar una pregunta de SOes a distintas preguntas de SO?

No. ([referencia](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/49332458#49332458))

> - ¿Tras la asociación y mapeo, el comentario sigue siendo necesario o se borra/puede borrarse?

Es mejor no hacerlo porque no hay ninguna indicación de que la pregunta esté asociada. Por tanto, podría ocurrir que alguien volviera a solicitar la asociación dejando un nuevo comentario. ([Referencia](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/49273217#49273217))

> - El usuario que puso el comentario solicitando una asociación, ¿recibe una notificación al respecto cuando se haga efectiva?

No.

> - ¿Funciona solo en el sitio principal o también en Meta?

Solamente en el sitio principal.