# ¿Debemos bloquear la publicación de enlaces a sitios con contenido traducido automáticamente?

Tags: discusión

Muchas gracias a [@Pikoh](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/15301/pikoh) por la traducción.

---

A medida que Stack Overflow en español crece, observamos una tendencia extremadamente negativa: vemos un aumento en los sitios que sólo contienen preguntas traducidas automáticamente de Stack Overflow en inglés al idioma español. El problema es que el contenido de la traducción automática en la mayoría de los casos es imposible de entender: a menudo una traducción es sólo un conjunto de palabras que se relacionan vagamente entre sí.

Defendemos el conocimiento sin fronteras lingüísticas, el conocimiento que es necesario e importante para las personas, el conocimiento que es apoyado por la comunidad. Los sitios con traducción automática son nuestras antípodas. Tal y como lo vemos, estos sitios no crean ningún valor humano, sino que sólo obstruyen los resultados de las búsquedas.

Creo que no deberíamos permitir enlaces a sitios con contenido traducido automáticamente en Stack Overflow en español, bloquear las publicaciones que tienen tales enlaces y mostrar un mensaje de error cuando un usuario intenta enviar uno:

> Su publicación contiene un enlace a un sitio cuyo contenido es una pregunta traducida automáticamente de Stack Overflow en inglés. Tales sitios obstruyen la Internet en español. Por favor, utilice un enlace a la pregunta original de Stack Overflow en inglés o elimine el enlace por completo.

Por favor, compartid vuestros pensamientos:

- ¿Deberían bloquearse esos sitios?
- Si es así, ¿qué mensaje de error os gustaría utilizar?
- Si conoces tales sitios y crees que deberíamos bloquearlos, por favor proporcionad una lista de direcciones URL.

Comment: Personally i'm not against this, but i really don't recall seeing too many cases of this in [es.so]. Could you provide any examples?

Comment: I see you are putting quite a lot of effort on this topic. It may be important, but I agree with @Pikoh that we lack examples. In the meanwhile, there are open topics which seem a bit forgotten now, such as [¿Queremos una pestaña “Sin respuestas” en la barra de navegación principal?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4339/83) and how is Stack Overflow going to work on international sites with regards with the [Updated pronouns CoC](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/336366/209901).

Comment: I think that we should have a blacklist of harmful sites no matter of what kind of harm they do but to blacklist a site should be clear the harm that they do or the risks for the users like those sites that allow ads from phishing / scamming sites including those site that stole content from other sites. Note I don't think that Meta (alone) is a good place to handle the blacklist process, perhaps a private chatroom or something like what is being done with translations (meta + chat + ad-hoc app i.e. traducir.win)

Answer (score 7):

I don't think this is a real problem: from the beginning in any SE an answer that is just a link to a third party site has been a candidate to be removed/downvoted to oblivion. In SOes even a link to SO is valid only in a comment or a side note in a real answer. A link to a machine translated site won't be useful unless the translation is pretty good and really gives a real answer to the question, so it will be downvoted or removed by mods.

Besides, I haven't seen any of these links here yet, so it's not like we have a spam issue.

To summarize: I am not against blocking those sites, but I don't think it will be worth the effort.

An offtopic thought: If someday AIs are able to translate Q&As from English to Spanish faithfullly, I think SE should be the main interested one in using that technology because it will multiply the knowledge's accessibility (a seamless union between SO and SOes, having all Q&A translated both ways, sounds like a dream for me).

#### En español (traducción aproximada):

No creo que sea un problema a día de hoy: desde siempre una respuesta que es sólo un enlace a un recurso externo se ha considerado una mala respuesta y se ha votado negativo o incluso *reportado* para que fuese borrada. En SOes incluso un enlace a SO en inglés es sólo válido como un comentario o como una nota dentro de una respuesta (no se se puede exigir que el OP sepa inglés).

Además, un enlace a una traducción automática sólo sería útil si la traducción fuera muy buena y diese una solución a la pregunta, con lo que un comentario con dicho enlace sería reportado y una pregunta votada negativa o editada para eliminar el enlace (si el resto de la respuesta es válida)

Y además aún no me he encontrado ni un solo enlace a uno de estos sitios (y reviso muchas preguntas cada día), con lo que tampoco es que estemos sufriendo un ataque de spammers con estos enlaces.

Por tanto, aunque no veo mal que se pueda hacer algo para bloquear estos enlaces, no creo que a día de hoy merezca el esfuerzo para el equipo de desarrolladores de StackExchange.

Un poco fuera de tema: Si algún día, mediante IA se pudiesen traducir preguntas y respuestas desde el inglés al español, creo que la red StackExchange sería la primera interesada en usar esta funcionalidad porque haría mucho más accesible a todos todo el conocimiento ya guardado en el sitio (*fusionar* SO y SOes, teniendo todas las preguntas en inglés y en español, sería grandioso).

Comment: y ru y pt tambien :)

Comment: Sobre lo que indicas de tener traducciones, sí sería bueno. Sin embargo, ya tenemos algo tremendamente interesante: [Asociación de preguntas entre SO y SOes](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3963/83).

Comment: ¿Pero eso es casi una forma de marcar duplicadas, más que de añadir contenido, no?